# Battery is not charging on a Dell Vostro 3750

Tags: battery, adapter

The chassis plug of this Vostro was broken off so I replaced it with a new one. After that I keep getting the message that the adapter is not recognized and that the battery will not charge. I also replaced the adapter by a genuine 90W one but I still keep getting this message and the battery still doesn't load. Is there anything to be reset after these repairs?

Comment: Are you sure the new plug is identical to the old one? Did the old plug have two or three connectors?